# property "getter object (DOMString name);" in the Document IDL

Tags: html, dom, specifications, w3c, idl

[HTML 5.1 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#dom-document-__getter__-name-name) define strange property in the Document IDL.

```
getter object (DOMString name);
```

It's not a typo and I don't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That part of the WebIDL definition for the `Document` interface specifies that it has a [named property getter](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-named-properties). It only has meaning in combination with [the section of the spec of the HTML spec that defines the supported property names for the `Document` interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-namedItem-which).

Together, those specify some things that get exposed as named properties of a `Document`.

Consider the following document:

```
<!doctype html>
<form name=foo></form>
<form name=bar></form>
<iframe name=bar></iframe>
<p id=baz>
```

If you call `document.foo` you’ll get back a single element, the `form name=foo` element.

If you call `document.bar` you’ll get back a collection that includes both the `form name=bar` element and `iframe name=bar` element.

And if you call `document.baz` you’ll get back `undefined`.

The reason for all that behavior is, the [section of the HTML spec defining the supported property names for the `Document` interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-namedItem-which) specifies that `form[name]` values and `iframe[name]` values are accessible as named properties of a `Document`

And [that spec section](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-namedItem-which) also says that if a `Document` named property  matches only one element, then that element is returned, but if it matches multiple elements, then a collection is returned.

And the reason `document.baz` returns `undefined` is because [that spec section](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-document-namedItem-which) does not specify `p[id]` values as being accessible as named properties of a `Document`.

However, if you instead do `window.baz` you *will* get back the `p id=baz` element.

The reason for that difference is: while the [WebIDL definition for `Window`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#the-window-object) specifies it is having a [named property getter](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-named-properties) (just as the `Document` WebIDL  does), the [section defining the supported property names for `Window`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object:window-3)—unlike the similar section for `Document`—*does* specify `p[id]` values (actually `id` values of *any* element) as being accessible as named properties of a `Window`.